# Ask |x| is sufficient statistic of $n(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

From the Factorization Theorem, the pdf or pmf of **X** can be written as $f(\textbf{x}|\theta) =g(T(\textbf{x})|\theta)h(\textbf{x})$ , where $g(t|\theta)$ is the pdf or pmf of *T* and $h(\textbf{x})$ does not depend on $\theta$.

I am confused on the statement "$g(t|\theta)$ is the pdf or pmf of *T*".

For example, this is the exercise 6.1 of Statistical Inference Book by Casella and Berger.

Let *X* be one observation from a $n(0,\sigma^2)$ population. Is $|X|$ a sufficient statistic?

I know how to solve this problem. The Factorization Theorem allows us to find a sufficient statistic by simple inspection of the pdf or pmf of the sample.

Thus, $f(x|\delta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2\sigma^2}}$.

My question is whether I can conclude $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ is the pdf of $|x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|X|$ is indeed sufficient for $\sigma^2$. This is quite intuitive, since $\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(-X)$, so the sign of your observation shouldn't matter in this context. You can't conclude that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2\sigma^2}} =: \phi(|x|)$ is the probability density function of $|X|$.

Since $|X|$ only takes non-negative values and $\phi(x)$ is an even function, it is quite intuitive to say that the pdf of $|X|$ is $2\phi(x)$ for $x \geq0$. If you are not convinced, here is the calculation:

**1)** ($x < 0)$ 
\begin{equation} 
P(|X| \leq x) = 0,
\end{equation}
since $|X|$ takes only non-negative values. 
**2)** $(x \geq 0)$
\begin{align} 
P(|X| \leq x) &= P(-x \leq X \leq x)  \\
&= P(X \leq x) -P(X \leq -x) ~\text{(because of symmetry)} \\
&= P(X \leq x) -P(X \geq x)  \\
&= P(X \leq x) -(1 - P(X \leq x)) \\
&= 2P(X \leq x) - 1.
\end{align}
If we differentiate wrt $x$, we obtain the density $2\phi(x)$.

With this, we can conclude that $|X|$ has the density function
\begin{equation}
f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x < 0,\\
      2\phi(x), & \text{if}\ x\geq0.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Aha, now I see. The $h(\textbf{x})$ in this case is $\frac 12$.

Comment: Ah, now I see why you've asked this. the function $g$ does not have to be the pdf of your sufficient statistic. It only has to non-negative. In this case you can take $g=f$ and $h=1$ and it will work.

Comment: But $g$ must be related to the pdf of the sufficient statistics. To be precise, $g$ must be the pdf of the sufficient statistics times a constant. Am I correct?

Comment: That's not what the theorem says. Take a look at Theorem 6.2.6 of your book.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if you check page 377 in the book, you can see that the textbook said "$g(t|\theta)$ is the pdf or pmf of *T*". (under Theorem 8.2.4)

Comment: But in this case, if we let $g$ be the pdf of $|X|$, then $f(x|\theta) = 1/2 g(|x||\theta)$. But it's not necessarily the case that we have this structure.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can use theorem 6.2.2 to see why this is the case.